# How do I rewrite a Haskell function that uses modifyIORef' to use atomicModifyIORef'

Tags: haskell, ioref

I am trying to solve a problem where Haskell gives different output to the same arguments. someone already has suggested that it could be a thread related issue.

I managed to rewrite a simple function to use the atomic version, but with more complex one I need help.

This is my code:

```
timeFun globalModel canvas = modifyIORef' globalModel (updateGlobalModel Tick) >> Gtk.widgetQueueDraw canvas >> return True
```

### My findings

Following the advice I tried to rewrite the function using do notation:

```
timerFun g c = do
  i <- readIORef g
  writeIORef g (updateGlobalModel Tick i)
  Gtk.widgetQueueDraw c
  return True
```

Version that uses atomic code and do notation:

```
timerFun g c = do
  atomicModifyIORef' g $ \p -> do
    (updateGlobalModel Tick p ,())
  Gtk.widgetQueueDraw c
  return True
```

Comment: Quick question: why are you using `>>` instead of `do`-notation here? This clearly breaks the 80-column rule.

Comment: You do not use the old value in `globalModel` here. Therefore switching to `atomicModifyIORef` won't change anything. You're going to need to do a bit of debugging work to determine the actual cause of your problem instead of shotgun changing things to see what works.

Comment: @AJFarmar, good question! how do I rewrite it in do notation?

Comment: @Daniel Wagner, where I can find advice about debugging Haskell programs?

Comment: @ruby_object Tutorial recommendations (and recommendations for offsite resources generally) go stale too quickly to be useful long-term. But I'm confident you have the skills needed to find advice on your own.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner You were right, switching to atomicModifyIORef did not work. But I still think I have learned something. Now I will read about debugging Haskell programs.

Answer (score 1):

The key to solving the problem was rewriting the function using do notation.

```
timerFun g c = do
  i <- readIORef g
  writeIORef g (updateGlobalModel Tick i)
  Gtk.widgetQueueDraw c
  return True
```

At this point I had writeIORef separated from other functions, so rewriting it using atomicModifyIORef' was trivial.

```
timerFun g c = do
  atomicModifyIORef' g $ \p -> 
    (updateGlobalModel Tick p, ())
  Gtk.widgetQueueDraw c
  return True
```

Same function with less syntactic sugar

```
timerFun g c = (atomicModifyIORef' g (\p -> (updateGlobalModel Tick p, ()))) >>
  Gtk.widgetQueueDraw c >>
  return True
```

Comment: I do not know, but the code appears to work. I am Haskell noob and I do not know what I am doing half of the time.